# Required textarea not turning red

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

The text boxes get red borders when text is removed from them. However, the textarea does not follow this behavior. What is the problem and how do I remedy it?

http://jsfiddle.net/cKYNy/9/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scaleable=no" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page_1" data-theme="b">


    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" style="padding:0px;margin:0;">
        <p>Content Page 1</p>
        <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" data-ajax="false" method="post">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" required="true"></input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="" required="true"></input>
        </div>
        <div>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="true"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></input>
        </div>
 </form>
    </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: turn red how? you add classes? if yes, show us the code pls.

Comment: @Omar I mean it gets a red border. This is done by jquery-mobile.

Comment: are you using jquery-validate? are you adding classes to empty input upon submit?

Comment: @Omar The code above is all I'm using, nothing else.

Comment: if you're testing your code on FF browser, its a browser feature. Edit: note that `required` and `required="true"` are not supported by all mobile browsers http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html

Comment: @Omar I'm testing in FF. It works until I include the stylesheets and javascripts in the head so I didn't think it was a FF issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39482/discussion-between-omar-and-baz)

Answer (score 0):

If it is not an option of JQuery Mobile you might wanna try the following:

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#name')[0].checkValidity() === false) {
        $('#name')[0].toggleClass("error");
    }
}
```

Catch the submit event on the form, stop it from submitting and check the validation yourself. If not valid, add an error class.